# OpenMP loop with variable amount of items

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm making an algorithm that could break a piece in sub-pieces... or not, and each sub-piece could be broken again etc.  Yes it is the perfect example for a recursive function but due to performance reasons I tried to do it in a parallel for.

```
omp_set_num_threads(omp_get_num_procs());
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for (int index = 0; index < toMakePartition.size(); index++)
{
    mItemClass* currItem = toMakePartition[index];
    makePartition(currItem);

    #pragma omp critical
    {
        for (int child = 0; child < currItem->children.size(); child++)
        {
            toMakePartition.push_back(currItem->children[child]);
        }  
        int numPartitionItems = toMakePartition.size();
        printf("END %i of %i   \n\n", index, numPartitionItems);
    }
}
```

The print shows that the `numPartitionItems` is growing correctly but unfortunately after the first loop it exits.  Without the OpenMP parallelism the algorithm works without any problem.

Any idea on how could I make this parallel version work?

Comment: please provide a complete example -- how do you run it?

Comment: Note: If you're considering to reformulate this as recursion, you could also use OpenMP tasks. But that would probably be a step back. From having the BFS-queue.